# uncovering slide animation at activity change in Android

Tags: android, animation

Hi I am applying animation at time of activity change like this.

```
Intent i;
        i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DemoActi.class);
        startActivity(i);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.push_left_in, R.anim.push_left_out);
```

xml file push_left_in in anim folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<translate
    android:duration="1500"
    android:fromXDelta="-100%"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/anticipate_overshoot_interpolator"
    android:toXDelta="0%" />

</set>
```

xml file push_left_out in anim folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<translate
    android:duration="1500"
    android:fromXDelta="0%"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/anticipate_overshoot_interpolator"
    android:toXDelta="100%" />

</set>
```

problem is that, I found an animation like MainActivity is going left to right and DemoActi is joining behind it same like train containers. but I need animation like DemoActi is covered by MainActivity and uncovering it at time of finish.
please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just put demoview on detail view and apply animation on it,,,,

```
    splash.clearAnimation();
    splash.startAnimation(bottomDownAnimation);
    splash.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```